# Having + past tense as a subject in a sentence?

Tags: questions, past-tense, sentence-patterns

is it possible to use the form "having + past tense" as a subject in a sentence? For example, is it grammatically correct to say:

> Having applied at the right time resulted in getting an admission.

Is *having applied* considered the subject in this sentence? My gut feeling tells me this sentence is correct, but I would like to be 100% sure. Thank you for help.

Best regrads,
Kate

Comment: It is correct. However, it would be the same to say "Applying at the right time resulted in ..."

Comment: Gustavson, thank you! Does it mean that "Applying at the right time resulted in ... " sounds more natural than what I wrote in my question?

Comment: The perfect form "having" + past participle emphasizes the sense of anteriority and should be used, in my opinion, only where strictly necessary. If there is immediacy or quasi-immediacy, the simple form V-ing is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

> Having applied at the right time resulted in getting admission.

This is the correct answer. Just a small mistake was there, you were using "an" before admission.

Comment: How is 'an admission' a mistake? 'Having applied' doesn't differ much from 'Applying' in this case.